# 500 errors on appengine and console

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Google Appengine in a production environment and we are currently getting 500 errors on both our website and console. Is there anything we can do to prevent these or handle them more gracefully?

EDIT: We're using python with Webapp

Comment: Which language are you using? Python with webapp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Setup error handlers: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Custom_Error_Responses
2. When the error occurs in the app, error handlers can't help. One solution is to wrap the application to handle uncaught exceptions:

   ```
   import logging

   from google.appengine.ext import webapp
   from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

   def error_handler_middleware(app):
       """Wraps the application to catch uncaught exceptions."""
       def wsgi_app(environ, start_response):
           try:
               return app(environ, start_response)
           except Exception, e:
               logging.exception(e)
               # ... display a custom error message ...
               response = webapp.Response()
               response.set_status(500)
               response.out.write('Ooops! An error occurred...')
               response.wsgi_write(start_response)
               return ['']

       return wsgi_app

   app = webapp.WSGIApplication([...])
   app = error_handler_middleware(app)

   def main():
       util.run_wsgi_app(app)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```
3. If you can, give [webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com) a try. You can set simple functions to [handle app-wide exceptions](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html#exceptions-in-the-wsgi-app).

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer moraes, will this kind of thing work for the console as well?

Comment: This middleware won't work in webapp - webapp already has a catchall handler that calls `handle_exception` and returns a 500. Overriding `handle_exception` - or better, just `error`, which `handle_exception` calls - in a base handler class is a better option.

Comment: Technically it will work; it will even catch 404's. But you are right that it is almost pointless; after checking webapp's code I see that, for non-404's, it already wraps dispatching and calls `.handle_exception()` from the matched handler. Still worth noting that webapp will only catch errors that happen on the request method (majority); it won't catch 404's, bad route definitions and the ones that happen on `__init__` and `initialize`.